# How does Jest test the B function called in the A function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

For example, give an example:

```js
// ListItem.tsx
interface Props {
    onTouchStart: (e: React.TouchEvent) => void;
}

const ListItem: React.FC <Props> = (props) => {
    const handleTouchStart = (e: React.TouchEvent) => {
        // Call the incoming function inside the component
        props.onTouchStart (e);
        // perform some other operations
    }

    return <div onTouchStart = {handleTouchStart}> </ div>
}

export default ListItem;
```

```js
// ListItem.test.tsx
import {createElement} from 'rax';
import renderer from 'rax-test-renderer';

it ('Test ListItem TouchStart', () => {
    const mockFunc = jest.fn ();
    const component = renderer.create (<ListItem onTouchStart = {mockFunc} />)
    const tree = component.toJSON ();
    tree.eventListeners.touchstart ();
    // report an error
    expect (tree.eventListeners.touchstart) .toHaveBeenCalled ();
})
```

```js
expect (received) .toHaveBeenCalled ()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type: function
    Received has value: [Function handleTouchStart]
```

How to test whether the function passing in props exists in the test case?

How to test whether the function passed in props is called in the test case?

Comment: `toHaveBeenCalled` expects a spy as the error tells, so you can check that the mock function has been called as follows `expect(mockFunc).toHaveBeenCalled()`. As for the first question - could you clarify what you mean? How cannot the function exist if you create it is the test?